# Unable to download files using urllib or requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to download the file from http://hdr.undp.org/en/indicators/137506#.

However, urllib gives me a 403 Forbidden error.

The code below gives me just HTTP response and not the csv file. Can someone help please.

```
import requests
# Define the remote file to retrieve
remote_url = 'http://hdr.undp.org/en/indicators/137506'
# Define the local filename to save data
local_file = 'local_copy.csv'
# Make http request for remote file data
data = requests.get(remote_url)
# Save file data to local copy
with open(local_file, 'wb')as file:
    file.write(data.content)
```

Comment: The javascript on page allows to download it, it seems, not the base URL

Comment: Thank you. So, is it not possible to download using Python? IS there another way than requests / urllib?

Comment: The actual file seems to be at https://bam-cell.nr-data.net/events/1/fe270b12c8?a=3267662&v=1210.e2a3f80&to=ZAAHMkVWD0IHVkZYWl1KMBReGE5YCFFXSRtDDRU%3D&rst=42559&ck=1&ref=http://hdr.undp.org/en/indicators/137506 and that link is generated via javascript.  You might want to look at Selenium if you are trying to do automated web scraping

Comment: Given that the data source doesn't change that often, you might just want to download it once manually and keep it with your project.  I assume you are doing some sort of analysis.  It looks like that data source might change once a year at most and might not be worth the effort to automate its capture

Comment: thanks guys, i am not trying to scrape. when i click download i get a nice csv file. Just need to find the right link/way to make that http request. the issue is there are many more files like this behind JS and doing this manually might not be viable. But, I guess I will follow your advice for now. Just download all the 20 files manually :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the different URL of the data fetched in the page, take what you need

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/bars.json',
    'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/footnotes.json',
    'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/rankiso.json',
    'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/aggregates.json',
    'http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/summary.json'
]

for remote_url in urls:
    data = requests.get(remote_url)
    print(remote_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.json())
    print(df.head(3).to_markdown())
    # df.to_csv("out.csv")
```

---

http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/bars.json

|  | indicator | iso3 | country | year | interval | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Refugees by country of origin (thousands) | AFG | Afghanistan | 2019 |  | 2721.47 | 21806 |
| 1 | Population with at least some secondary education (% ages 25 and older) | AFG | Afghanistan | 1990 |  | 8.2 | 23806 |
| 2 | Population with at least some secondary education (% ages 25 and older) | AFG | Afghanistan | 1995 |  | 9.8 | 23806 |

http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/footnotes.json

|  | footnote_id | indicator_id | iso3 | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | kkk | 21806 | PSE | 2019 |
| 1 | uuuu | 21806 | PSE | 2019 |
| 2 | uuuu | 21806 | NPL | 2019 |

http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/rankiso.json

|  | iso3 | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AFG | 169 |
| 1 | AGO | 148 |
| 2 | ALB | 69 |

http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/aggregates.json

|  | indicator_id | country_or_hierarchy_id | aggregation_type | aggregation_point_name | aggregation_id | sort_order | year | value | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 21806 | 302 | Human Development | Very high human development | 1 | 1 | 2018 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 21806 | 202 | Human Development | High human development | 1 | 2 | 2018 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 21806 | 102 | Human Development | Medium human development | 1 | 3 | 2018 |  | 1 |

http://hdr.undp.org/sites/all/themes/hdr_theme/js/summary.json

|  | id | dimension | indicator | source | definition | sdg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 21806 | Human security | Refugees by country of origin (thousands) | UNHCR .... | Number of people ... | ... situations |
| 1 | 23806 | Education | Population with at least some secondary education (% ages 25 and older) | UNESCO .. | Percentage ... | ... |
| 2 | 23906 | Education | Population with at least some secondary education, female (% ages 25 and older) | UNESCO ... | Percentage of .. | SDG 4.4 .. |

Comment: Is there a way to see what URL comes up when you click on download data please? The status bar just shows http://hdr.undp.org/en/indicators/137506#

Comment: @RThatha all the 5 URLs  are fetched to build the data, I don't know are they are concatenated together

Comment: Wow, this is better than I was hoping for. bars.json has all the data I required. Download JS seems to be just working as a filter. But if I get bars.json I have everything I needed. Thanks a lot.